# Back to my activity from the browser

Tags: android, browser, android-activity

I have an activity that takes an "intent" to the browser, I see the page on which connect and when I return to my work I press the button to go back to my activity. The problem is that it gets stuck in the browser. Is there any solution? Thank you very much for everything and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have problems with browser you can easily created your own activity with WebView and there add button "back to app" or just override back button.

Using this you will have full control.

Comment: Thank you very much I will prove it.